# Tox 0% coverage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, tox, coverage.py

I have a python project where I use:

- pipenv
- tox
- pytest

and many more.

Basically, I want to add `tox` to my gitlab pipelines. And almost everything seems to work, calling `mypy`, `flake8` or `black` from tox works fine. But when I call `tox -e py37` (so I want to run the tests) with coverage enabled, the tests are run, I can see their results, but the coverage is `0%`  (`100%` only on empty `__init__` files etc.) and I get the warning: `Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)`.

This is my pytest-relevant part of `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = flake8,mypy,black,py37

[testenv]
extras = tests
commands=
    pytest --cov -ra --tb=short {posargs}
```

And this is my `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
branch = True
source =
    foo

omit = 
    foo/__init__.py
    foo/__main__.py
    foo/bar/__init__.py
    foo/baz/__init__.py

[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    if __name__ == .__main__.
show_missing = True
```

I have a working `setup.py` which includes all needed packages: `pytest`, `pytest-cov` and many more for style etc. (which works). I also have `__init__.py` in my `tests` folder.

Funny thing is, if I call the same command I have in `tox.ini` from my command line (in `pipenv`): `pytest --cov -ra --tb=short`, I get the same results but with normal coverage (in my case it's `100%`).

Is there a way to fix it? I don't want my pipelines to show wrong coverage + even if they somehow magically would actually get the right one, I still would want to see it locally.

P.S When I was trying to resolve the issue I called tox with `tox --sitepackages -e py37` and I got some errors like `test command found but not in testenv`. And besides those errors, my coverage was fine then. But then I uninstalled `tox`, `pytest` and `pytest-cov` from my global pip register and now with or without `--sitepackages` flag I still get `0%` coverage

Comment: `--cov` expects an argument, e.g. package name or source directory or file, e.g. `pytest --cov=foo.bar` etc.

Comment: `.coveragerc` takes care of that. Plus it wouldn't work from the command line if that was the issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The root-cause** is that `pytest` during runnung `tox` uses the installed sources (under site-packages) while the coverage reporter count the hits files in the working directory (ie. your local git repo).

---

**Solution**

Add the tox's virtual-env path to coverage:

```
[testenv]
pytest --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/foo
```

For more detail read [substitutions for virtualenv-related sections](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections)

---

**Work-around**

Set `PYTHONPATH` to working directory (ie. `export PYTHONPATH=.`). Note, that you need to pass the `PYTHONPATH` to `tox` by:

```
[testenv]
passenv =
    PYTHONPATH
```

This is easy, but using this way, you don't test the installation, because the tests runs on the files in the working directory.

Comment: Forgot to mention, sorry, I actually solved the issue by placing empty `__init__.py` file in all of the tests directory directories. Don't know why, but it works. But I also checked your answer and it works as well, so I am marking it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @dabljues that works because pytest adds your source directory to the PYTHONPATH - you should be testing the package installed by tox instead

Comment: using `python -m pytest` also seem to work, for a similar reason - python -m adds `.` to PATH

Answer (score 7):

##### Trivial solution

Have `usedevelop=True` in the tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
usedevelop=True
pytest --cov=foo
```

which results in the same behavior as @zvi-baratz's solution but is less hacky.

##### Caveat

The only caveat here is that if the package has a custom `install_command` this solution can not be used. Please see the [docs](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-usedevelop) for more info.

If that is the case, you can use `--cov={envsitepackagesdir}/foo` as a
**work-around**.

##### Why not just use `envsitepackagesdir` all the time?

Because it results in the coverage report having lengthier paths that point to files in the python environment created by tox instead of the actual project path.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @betontalpfa's answer, I think another possible solution (seems to work well in my use case) is to modify `tox.ini` to include:

```
[testenv]
deps = -e .
...
```

AFAIK, By installing the package in the working directory using pip's editable mode, you get to both test the installed package and avoid the file path mismatch causing the 0% coverage score.