# Recording coverage from a tox-installed wheel

Tags: python, tox, coverage.py

I have a problem similar to [Tox 0% coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696476/tox-0-coverage), but I do have *some* coverage. My runtime code is being covered, but my test code is not. I have built [an example app](https://github.com/kojiromike/example-python-package/tree/coverage-ignores-tests) that reproduces the problem.

```
Name                                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/org/app/__init__.py            0      0   100%
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/org/app/app.py                 2      0   100%
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/org/app/test/__init__.py       0      0   100%
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/org/app/test/test_it.py        5      5     0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                7      5    29%
```

One hypothesis might be that unittest is only actually running `src/org/app/test/test_it.py`, and never running `.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/org/app/test/test_it.py`. But the unittest command is `coverage run --omit 'src/**' -m unittest discover '{envsitepackagesdir}/org/app'`, which I would expect to cause discovery to look for tests inside the site-packages directory. Here is the whole tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py38

[testenv]
deps = coverage
commands_pre = coverage erase
download = true
commands = coverage run --omit 'src/**' -m unittest discover '{envsitepackagesdir}/org/app'
commands_post = coverage report

[coverage:run]
source_pkgs = org.app

[coverage:paths]
source =
    ${TOX_ENV_DIR-src}/org/app
    src/org/app

[coverage:report]
exclude_lines =
    def __repr__
    if 0:
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
    if self.debug:
    if settings.DEBUG
    pragma: no cover
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
```

How can I get coverage to report the test in site-packages as having been run, or get test discovery to actually run that test instead of the same test someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was due to my mistaken thinking about how `coverage` handles the `source` directive. For the commands being run by tox, directly, I need to supply `--source` explicitly:

```
[testenv]
commands = coverage run --source '{envsitepackagesdir}/org/app' --omit 'src/**' -m unittest discover '{envsitepackagesdir}/org/app'
```

then, removing the `[coverage:paths]` section and setting the source in `[coverage:run]`:

```
[coverage:run]
source = src/org/app
```

will enable someone to directly run `coverage run -m pytest` or `pytest --cov` and get accurate coverage outside of the toxenv. They won't interfere.